# Select com base em um combobox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

[image]Tenho um sistema com mapa interativo para cadastro de empresas. Ao clicar em um estado ele abre um `<select>` com os segmentos de empresas daquele estado, porém ao selecionar um segmento ele me mostra as empresas de todos os estados que possuem aquele segmento ao invés de mostrar as empresas apenas do estado selecionado. Ou seja, se houver o mesmo segmento em mais de um estado ele lista todas as empresas daquele segmento ignorando o estado selecionado, conforme mostrado na imagem. Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar isso? Já percebi que o problema pode estar na consulta do banco de dados, pois ele não está matando uma consulta pra iniciar a outra. Quando clica em outro Estado ele apenas acrescenta esse estado ao que foi selecionado anteriormente.

Código Ajax

```
function abre_estado(codigo){

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:"codigo="+codigo,
        url:"altera_estado.php",
        success: function(msg){

            $('#segmentos').hide(msg);
            $('#segmentos').html(msg);
            $('#segmentos').fadeIn(msg);

            }
        });

    }

function abre_empresa(codigo){

$.ajax(
{

    url: 'consulta_empresa.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "codigo="+codigo,
    success: function(data)
    {
        var data = data;
        $('#centro-direita').html(data).fadeIn();
    }


});
```

Código altera_estado.php

```
$id_estado= $_POST['codigo'];

$consultaSegmentos = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM `empresas` AS e INNER JOIN `segmentos` as s ON (e.segempresas = s.idseg)  WHERE `ufempresas` = '$id_estado'  GROUP BY `segempresas`");
$consultaSegmentos->execute();
$fetchAll = $consultaSegmentos->fetchAll();


foreach ($fetchAll as $segmentos)
{
    <option value="<?php echo $segmentos['idseg'];?>"><?php  echo $segmentos['segmento'];?></option>
```

Código consulta_empresa.php

$id_segmento= $_POST['codigo'];

```
$consultaEmpresas = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM `empresas` AS e 
INNER JOIN `estados` AS t ON (e.ufempresas = t.codigo) WHERE 
`ufempresas` = '1' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '2' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '3' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '4' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '5' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '6' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '7' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '8' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '9' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '10' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '11' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '12' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '13' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '14' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '15' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '16' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '17' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '18' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '19' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '20' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '21' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '22' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '23' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '24' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '25' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '26' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento' OR
`ufempresas` = '27' AND `segempresas` = '$id_segmento'");
$consultaEmpresas->execute();

echo " 
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <td>NOME DA EMPRESA</td>
                    <td>ESTADO</td>
                    <td>LINK RH</td>
                </thead>
            ";
while ($empresas = $consultaEmpresas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    <div id="centro-direita-select">
        <tbody width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="67%"><?php echo $empresas['nome']; ?></td>
                      <td width="10%"><?php echo $empresas['sigla']; ?></td>
                      <td><a href ="<?php echo $empresas['url']; ?>"target=_blank"</a>Clique para acessar</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque no seu javascript:

```
function busca_empresas(uf, segmento_id){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'busca_empresa.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {uf_empresa: uf, segmento: segmento_id},
        dataType: 'JSON', 
        success: function(dados){

            let html = "";

            html += "";
            html += "";
            html += "NOME DA EMPRESA";
            html += "ESTADO";
            html += "LINK RH";
            html += "";

            $.each(dados, function(i, empresa){

                html += "";
                html += "";
                html += "";
                html += ""+empresa.nome+"";
                html += ""+empresa.sigla+"";
                html += "target='_blank'Clique para acessar";
                html += "";
                html += "";
                html += "";

            });

            html += "";

            //aqui vc coloca a tabela no elemento do seu html
            elemento.innerHTML = html;

        }

    });
```

Crie o arquivo busca_empresa.php e coloque o código:

```
$uf_empresa = $_POST['uf_empresa'];
$segmento_id = $_POST['segmento_id'];

$consultaEmpresas = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas AS e INNER JOIN estados AS t ON (e.ufempresas = t.codigo) WHERE e.ufempresas = :ufempresa AND e.segempresas = :segmento_id");
$consultaEmpresas->bindParam(":ufempresa", $uf_empresa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consultaEmpresas->bindParam(":segmento_id", $segmento_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consultaEmpresas->execute(); 

while($empresas = $consultaEmpresas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $registros[] = array(
        "nome" => $empresas['nome'],
        "sigla" => $empresas['sigla'],
        "url" => $empresas['url']
    );
}

echo json_encode($registros);
```